# Amazon Elastic MapReduce: Exception from FileSystem

Tags: amazon-s3, mapreduce

I run my application using ruby client:
ruby elastic-mapreduce -j j-20PEKMT9BRSUC --jar s3n://sakae55/lib/edu.cit.som.jar --main-class edu.cit.som.hadoop.SOMDriver --arg s3n://sakae55/repository/input/ecoli/ --arg s3n://sakae55/repository/output/ecoli/pl/ --arg s3n://sakae55/repository/data/ecoli/som.txt

Then, I am seeing the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This file system object (file:///) does not support access to the request path 'hdfs://i
-10-195-207-230.ec2.internal:9000/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/mapred/system/job_201004221221_0017/job.jar' You possibly called Fi
eSystem.get(conf) when you should of called FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:676)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.configureCommandLineOptions(JobClient.java:662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1026)
        at edu.cit.som.hadoop.SOMDriver.runIteration(SOMDriver.java:106)
        at edu.cit.som.hadoop.SOMDriver.train(SOMDriver.java:69)
        at edu.cit.som.hadoop.SOMDriver.run(SOMDriver.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at edu.cit.som.hadoop.SOMDriver.main(SOMDriver.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.run(JobShell.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.main(JobShell.java:68)

I am not sure why the error references to "file:///" even though all the arguments I pass do not use the schema.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the reuse of the JobConf object was causing this issue. Changing the code to create a new instance for each iteration solved the problem.